# Abandon Session Without Clearing All

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

**Overview :** 
I created a system that have Customer area and Admin area. Both areas have different log-in page. A user can be logged in as *User A* in Admin area at the same time logged in as *User B* in Customer area.

When a user log-out from either Customer or Admin area, `Session.Abandon()` is called and it removes session in both Customer and Admin area **which I don't want to happen**

**Question :** Can I abandon session on log-out without affecting other area's session ? (i.e : When I log out from Customer area, I should stay logged-in in Admin area)

**Update :** I know `Session.Clear()` can be a workaround for this, but I'm afraid of the security risks it might impose.

Comment: Would it be simpler to implement these are two separate websites?

Comment: No! abandon session resulting in clearing all session.
You could use session.remove("Keyname") to remove specific session

Comment: are you using the same session for both areas ? try using two different session

Comment: How are they logged-in ? You probably don't use FormsAuthentication, I don't see how you can be logged-in twice in the same application... Is it a custom solution ?

Comment: @RichardEv : It would be simpler it is. But it's not and separating this into two different website would be alot of work.

Comment: @ShoaibMuhammadKhan : I understand, but wouldn't clearing instead of abandoning will pose some security risks?

Comment: @Sora : It's different session key but the same SessionID.

Comment: @Guillaume : Yes, it's a custom solution. I prefer to keep it this way unless there are no other solutions.

Comment: @xar so, it will be hard to tell you how to logout an user if we don't know how they are logged. You seem to use an unique session to keep two separate logins. So, you have to clear only the part of session matching the current area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core of the problem is that normally for **one** asp web application there is **only one session** (*) per the physical user's browser. Without some really serious modifications to the site/frame/servercode structure, you are not able to create and mantain several parallel sesisons. Even your ".Session" hashmap provided by Pages and Controls always show the same keys/values..

Some parts of your web app may use different keys and thus emulate "layers" or "modules" that does not intersect, but still this is only one storage..

Thus, if you call Session-Abandon, you lose all - because it wa only one session out there..

The only thing youcan do is to manually selectively clear the proper entries, like Rolice answered here in parallel:)

(*) actually, when you do a Session-Abandon you are not removing/destroying the session. There still is an exactly one session. It has just forgotten all the data and now it is "empty" = so, like new. Well, ok, it maybe removes the old cookies, I dont remember, but they will be re-created with new fresh keys instantly upon next page render, so ... rather immediatelly.

Comment: Is there any potential security risk if I selectively remove session instead of abandoning it?

Comment: Well, everything you forget to clear/remove simply stays there till the real end of the session. So, the risk depends solely on what you keep in the session and whether you allow to add&run 3rd party code modules on your site. Session is one and global, so any module on your currently-displayed web page may have access to it.The same applies to ViewState and ControlState and other state-bags present in your web engine. However,note that the session is kept at server and only the session key is in the cookies-so only SERVER-side code modules apply. Your server. Google-stats etc will not see it.

Comment: But this applies to the session, and **does not** apply to the ViewState/ControlState and similar state bags. They are serialized and embedded in the page's HTML code as a hidden form field - thus they are completely insecure, and any code that can read the HTML can potentially also read the data put inside them. This is why it was called ViewState - "the data that are held along with the View".  If you want to know how your state-bags behave, you must check it yourself or in the docs of your framework. ViewState/ControlState exists in the base ASP.NET, and may be named differently in MVC.

Comment: Note: session is relatively safe even if you forget to clear something, as long as you trust the code at the server. I assume you are using well-known server side modules.. And the warning about ViewState/ControlState/etc applies only if you forget to clear a some sensitive keys. If you are sure that you have removed all, then it is safe. Or at least as safe as it was, because if you kept sensitive data in ViewState, then probably the evil guys already have read them :wink: I'm joking a bit, but be careful about using them.

Answer (score 1):

Write your function that checks if the session's customer id is > 0, username is not empty and ip is equal to remote ADDR.

Store the customer_id, customer_username and IP (for security) in the session and clear only them.
When you call your function it will return that user is not signed as customer.

The same applies for admin.

It is not necessary to destroy (abandon) the session, keep it alive and store additional info.

```
public bool IsLoggedIn()
{
    // You will have to check for the keys, if they are present in the Session container, first.

    if(!Session.Containts("customer_id")
            || !Session.Contains("customer_username")
            || !Session.Contains("customer_ip"))
        return false;

    return Session["customer_id"] > 0
        && String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["customer_username"])
        && Session["customer_ip"] = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
}

public void LogOut()
{
    Session.Remove("customer_id");
    Session.Remove("customer_username");
    Session.Remove("customer_ip");
}
```